# discord.py ban all members command

Tags: python, discord

I'm working on a bot for educational use and I'm looking for a banall command I seen the others but it doesn't work no errors just when I use it nothing executes

This is what I used

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def banall(ctx):
    for member in list(ctx.guild.members):
      try:
        await member.ban(reason='test')
      except:
        pass
        await ctx.message.delete()
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `try/except` statement so we can actually see what error messages are being generated? Saying there's no error messages is made rather redundant when you're catching them and ignoring them.

Comment: I can do that but what I mean by no errors is when I do !banall it does nothing and it shows no error like it shows nothing was even executed

Comment: Okay, can you also add a print statement, like `print("banall command")` to prove that it _is_ being executed? Is the original `!banall` message being deleted?

Comment: Yes, when you put `except: pass`, that suppresses errors. You're literally telling Python you don't want to see any errors, which makes it very hard to identify what the errors *are*.

Comment: Yes when I do !banall it deletes it and I took out the except and try and just kept the delete message and it still did the same thing

Comment: Let me try the print

Comment: When you say you just kept the `delete` message, did you also take out the bit banning members? Cos that bit needs to stay in if we want to see what's going wrong with it. It deleting the original `banall` message is proof enough that the function is actually getting executed.

Comment: Yea the command stays it runs but when I type !banall it deletes the message and does nothing at all

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1072050357154369566/1072166738860445726/lv_0_20230206084736.mp4 here's a video of what I mean

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that `guild.members` isn't fully populated - so we need to [fetch the members](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.fetch_members) to be able to ban them.  You will need the `members` Intent enabled though to do so.

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def banall(ctx):
    async for member in ctx.guild.fetch_members():
        try:
            await member.ban(reason='test')
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Exception {e} banning {member}")
    await ctx.message.delete()
```

Modified the `try/except` so that it will at least print an error message if it has an issue banning a member.

[Member intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html#member-intent).

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1072050357154369566/1072168282964111380/Screenshot_20230206_085351.jpg

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1072050357154369566/1072168282712461492/Screenshot_20230206_085338.jpg

Comment: This is what the error said

Comment: How do you define your `intents`? You will need to enable the `members` one as I said to do so.